# validation for either or dynamic textbox in mvc3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-validate

I have a form that form loads a partial view when i select the dropdown values.Here the partialview loads two dynamic textbox with different ID values.

```
@model List<DataBaseModel.OrderQuoteTBvalues>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_ingroundDynamic";
}

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="20%">
                        <tr style="background-color: #808080; color: #fff; font-size: 14px;">
                            <th align="left" width="100px">Pool Shape Type</th>
                            <th align="center" width="20px">Feet<br>
                                <th align="left" width="20px">Inch</th>
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@item.Shape_type</td>
                                <td>
                                  <input style="width: 100px;" type="text" onkeydown="Integerkeydown(event)" id="PF:@item.Shape_type" name="PF:@item.Shape_type" /></td>

                                <td>
                                    <input style="width: 100px;" type="text" onkeydown="Numerickeydown(event)" onchange="PIChange(this)" id="PI:@item.Shape_type" name="PI:@item.Shape_type" maxlength="4" /></td>
                            </tr>

                       }
}
```

Here the model is as follows:

```
 public class OrderQuoteTBvalues
            {
                public string Shape_type { get; set; }
            }
```

After that i have placed the next button onSubmit. if i click the Next button means i need to validate, either or textbox contains value. if it contains the value the validation true else false.
How to achieve that. Need to write any Custom Validation Method?.. If i give class="required" means all textbox is validated. but i need either or textbox to be validated.? Please help me to solve this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Give same class to both textbox and check if any textbox is having value using class for validation through jquery

Comment: any sample code @Nitinvarpe

Comment: @Nitinvarpe please help me to fix this issue..

Comment: I dont understand your problem. You want to validate any one textbox that has value ? So, the other textbox will remain empty ?

Comment: yeah.. but any one of the textbox contains value..

Comment: So you want to ignore the empty textbox and validate the textbox with value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Jquery

```
 $("#validate").live({ 
        click: function() {

       var rows = $("#your_table tr:gt(0)"); // your_table is id of you table---gt(0) to skip first row
       var i=true;

                rows.each(function(index) {
        var firsttext = $("td:nth-child(1) input", this).val();
        var secondtext = $("td:nth-child(2) input", this).val();
                   if(firsttext=="" && secondtext=="")
                       i=false;
            });
   if(i==true)
      alert('Valid'); 
            else
                alert("Invalid")
        }
    });
```

Child differ according to your order so correct that
Hope it helps leave comment if not understood

Comment: that means i have to give id value for <tr id="txtrow">

Comment: No dear only specify id for your table which in my case is #your_table and validate is id for button

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnNext").click( function() {
var valid = false;

   if($("#table tr").length > 0) {

    var textbox1 = $("table tr td:nth-child(1) input", this).val();
    var textbox2 = $("table tr td:nth-child(2) input", this).val();

    if(textbox1=="" && textbox2==""){
      valid = false;
     }
    else if(textbox1 != "" && textbox2 != "") {
     valid = false;
    }
    else {
     valid = true;
     }
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the output will be like this friends.

Comment: Have u found solution? have you tried  onfocusout of textbox and pass id's of both textbox to function which u r going to call on onfocusout

Comment: No @Nitinvarpe can u give me ur Emailid